# aws configure command not working on cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Command "aws  configure" giving following error ! This command was working before !

"aws  configure" :

```
$ aws  configure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 44, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 53, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=emitter)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/plugin.py", line 49, in load_plugins
    plugin.awscli_initialize(event_hooks)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/handlers.py", line 73, in awscli_initialize
    register_removals(event_handlers)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/customizations/removals.py", line 32, in register_removals
    'verify-email-address'])
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/customizations/removals.py", line 45, in remove
    self._create_remover(remove_commands))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 64, in register
    self._verify_accept_kwargs(handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 84, in _verify_accept_kwargs
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 936, in getargspec
    raise ValueError("Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations"
ValueError: Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations, use getfullargspec() API which can support them
```

Can't understand what is the "ValueError"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have just upgraded python to 3.4.1.

The version of the AWS CLI and botocore hosted for Ubuntu 14.04 is incompatible with python 3.4.1+. ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awscli/+bug/1501042))

The version of the CLI installed via apt-get is out of date. Python 3.4.1 introduced a breaking change with the getargspec() function, which we use in botocore. ([source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/800))

You can try: (I don't have testbox with me to verify)

```
sudo apt-get remove awscli
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install awscli
sudo pip install upgrade botocore
```

Comment: My Python version 
# python --version
Python 2.7.6

Comment: $ sudo pip install upgrade botocore
Downloading/unpacking upgrade
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement upgrade
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for upgrade
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ashish/.pip/pip.log

Comment: $ cat /home/ashish/.pip/pip.log
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Thu Oct  1 16:12:13 2015
Downloading/unpacking upgrade
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/upgrade/
  URLs to search for versions for upgrade:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/upgrade/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/upgrade/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement upgrade
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
No distributions at all found for upgrade

Comment: Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Seems aws cli doesn't work well with python 3.

> inspect.getargspec(func)
>
> Get the names and default values of a Python function’s arguments. A named tuple ArgSpec(args, varargs, keywords, defaults) is returned. args is a list of the argument names. varargs and keywords are the names of the * and ** arguments or None. defaults is a tuple of default argument values or None if there are no default arguments; if this tuple has n elements, they correspond to the last n elements listed in args.
>
> Deprecated since version 3.0: Use signature() and Signature Object, which provide a better introspecting API for callables. This function will be removed in Python 3.6.

Can you try with python 2.6 or 2.7?

```
Requires Python 2.6.5 or higher.
```

Refer:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec

https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with these steps

```sh
sudo pip3 uninstall awscli
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 1
sudo pip3 install awscli
```

Comment: Hey Mahmoud!  Welcome to stack overflow, and thanks for answering the question.  You can make your answer even better by adding explanation as to what is happening and why this is a solution.  See more at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK, I will do 
Thank you Robsiemb